# Can I ask for a critique of an aspect of our development process?

Tags: discussion, site-topic

For example, would it be considered off-topic if:

I posted some project requirements along with corresponding User Stories I created and asked for a critique of my stories?

I'm pretty sure I already know the answer, but I figured I'd ask anyway

Comment: A general critique is off-topic. However, we can help if there is a particular problem you are trying to resolve.